# PODs Templates Not Displaying in DIVI Theme

Tags: wordpress, divi, podscms

I have a Wordpress site that is using the DIVI Theme and PODs CMS to create and display custom Content Types. I cannot get any of the PODs data to display. A simple PODs Content Type I have created is setup like the following.

**Label:** Portal Phone

**Name:** `portal_phone`

**Fields:**

*FieldName - DataType*

- `related_user_id` - Plain Number
- `name` - String
- `phone_number` - Phone

There are the standard audit and ID fields for the POD as well.

I am only trying to have the `name`-`phone_number` display in a bulleted list to just verify that the data can be displayed. Presently there is no filter on the CustomTemplate I have specified. Also of note I have tried the pluralized form of `portal_phones` and an error displays saying `Pods embed error: Pod not found`

Template

```
[pods name="portal_phone" shortcodes="1"]
  [before]<ul>[/before]
  [if portal_phone]
    [each portal_phone]
      <li>{@name}-{@phone_number}</li>
    [/each]
  [/if]
  [after]</ul>[/after]
[/pods]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pods embed error: Pod not found` suggests the `[pods name="PODNAME"]` is not defined as PODS.

Try adding the name attribute correctly.